# Understanding Variance Treshold

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am working on a text classification problem in python, where I build a traing array based on {0,1} if the word is inside the text or not.

```
array([[0., 1., 1., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 1., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 1., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       ...,
       [0., 1., 1., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 1., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 1., ..., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

as I want to run SVM on it, I want to reduce my features. In scikit learn I found this: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html
with the Variance Threshold set to:

```
sel = VarianceThreshold(threshold=(.8 * (1 - .8)))
x_train_red = sel.fit_transform(x_train)
```

from the reduction I am reducing my shape from:

```
(7808, 2000)
(7808, 97)
```

does it only reduce the futre where every line has 1 or where every line has a 0 or how does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation you can see the variance is calculated by p(1-p), the default threeshold or limit 0.8 means that any column with a probability of having 0 variance above 0.8 will be eliminated. So it deletes the columns with rare occurrences, those words are not in your text a lot, so their variance will be close to 0 and the feature selection will eliminate it.

Comment: so it could be that a column has : `0,0,0,0,0...,0,1`and will get eliminated?

Comment: yes, if your column is [0,0,0,0,0,0.....,1] it will be eliminated as it has low variance